# Writing to Execl in C# Causing System.__ComObject

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to write data from a `List<string>` to a cell in an Excel file.

The code can been seen below as I attempt to write the strings in the List "rawDTCs" to an excel sheet.

```
for (int x = 0; x < rawDTCs.Count; x++)
{
     excelWorkSheet.Cells[myRow, 25] += rawDTCs[x];
}
```

Instead of getting the strings in the list, I receive the following.

[image]

Do I need to cast my array list to avoid getting this error? How can I make it so the strings in the list print to the cells?

Comment: The += operator will invoke the ToString() method on a Range.  Which produces System.__ComObject.  You'll have to convert the Value property to a string or use the Text property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this.

```
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorkSheet.Cells[myRow, 25]).Value2 = 
rawDTCs[x];
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, it will not let me use the .Value operation.